# Adding a line terminator to a string

Tags: c

I receive some parameters that I transform into  `char` and concatenate to create a string that is written into a  `.txt` file. I tried adding a  `0` at the end of said string as a line terminator. However, when I use  `file 10.txt` on my ubuntu terminal, I get  `10.txt: ASCII text, with no line terminators`

What do I need to change in order to add a line terminator?

```
int main() {
    int res;
    res = set_value(10, "abc", 3, 2.0);
}

int set_value(int key, char *value1, int value2, double value3) {
    char name[1000];
    int status;
    char line[5000];
    char temp[1000];
    int n;

    // Change directory where we work.
    if (chdir("FilesPractice1") == -1) {
        perror("Error while changing directories.");
        return -1;
    }

    // Convert key to the name of the file.
    snprintf(name, 1000, "%d.txt", key);

    // Open the file.
    if ((status = open(name, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        // Since the file doesnt exist, we proceed to create it.
        if ((status = open(name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666)) == -1) {
            perror("Error while creating the tuple.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        // Format the key and values to write them into the file.
        snprintf(line, 5000, "%d, ", key);
        
        n = strlen(value1);
        strncat(line, value1, n);
        
        snprintf(temp, 1000, ", %d, ", value2);
        n = strlen(temp);
        strncat(line, temp, n);
        
        snprintf(temp, 1000, "%f", value3);
        n = strlen(temp);
        strncat(line, temp, n);
        
        n = strlen(line);
        line[n + 1] = 0;

        // Write the values into the file.
        write(status, line, strlen(line));

    } else {
        // Since file already exists, it is considered an error.
        perror("Error: key value already exists.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Close the file.
    if (close(status) == -1) {
        perror("Error while closing the file.");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C will stop before the null when calculating the string length because it's the C line terminator. Did you want to write the null to the file? Or are you rather looking for the newline character?

Comment: This doesn't compile as-is.  But perhaps your problem is that you think a "line terminator" is a null character, but it's a newline (or some variant thereof).

Comment: `open()` returning -1 doesn't indicate that the file doesn't already exist. It may fail for about 40 different reasons according to the man page. You need to examine to value of `errno` (it is set to `EEXIST` if the file already exists) to be sure of that.

Comment: Note that `strlen()` doesn't include the null-terminator. It's unclear what your question is.

Comment: 0 is a string terminator, not a cr/lf.

Comment: 0x1E, the ASCII Record Separator character, might be suitable too depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using `write()` instead of `fprintf()` to write to your file?  It looks like `fprintf()` would be cleaner, clearer, and easier.

Comment: Also, presumably you are using `strncat()` because you want it to help you avoid overrunning your buffer, but your particular use is not effective for that.  You are just assuming that there is enough space for whatever part you are adding next.  If you stick with assembling each line in memory before printing it, then you should handle that correctly.  In fact, a single `snprintf()` for the whole line would be much better than the multiple `snprintf` and `strncat` calls you are now using.

Answer (score 1):

In order to append a newline to the string, just use `strcat(line, "\n");`

Also note these remarks:

- calling `strncat(line, temp, strlen(temp))` is exactly equivalent to `strcat(line, temp)`.
- you forget to close the file if it already exists.
- the `set_value` function should be defined or at least declared before the `main` function.

There is no reason to use separate calls to `snprintf` in your code, you could simply write:

```
    snprintf(line, sizeof line, "%d, %s, %d, %f\n",
             key, value1, value2, value3);
```

If you must for some reason construct the output line one field at a time, you can simplify the code by keeping track of the position in the output line instead of using separate arrays for the fragments and concatenating them with `strcat`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int set_value(int key, char *value1, int value2, double value3) {
    char filename[32];
    int status;
    char line[5000];

    // Change directory where we work.
    if (chdir("FilesPractice1") == -1) {
        perror("Error while changing directories.");
        return -1;
    }

    // Convert key to the name of the file.
    snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "%d.txt", key);

    // Open the file.
    if ((status = open(filename, O_RDONLY)) != -1) {
        // The file already exists, close it and report the error
        close(status);
        // Cannot use `perror` as `errno` was not set
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: key value file %s already exists.\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }

    // Since the file doesn't exist, we proceed to create it.
    if ((status = open(name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666)) == -1) {
        perror("Error while creating the tuple.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // Format the key and values to write them into the file.
#if 0
    // Single call to snprintf
    size_t pos = snprintf(line, sizeof line, "%d, %s, %d, %f\n",
                          key, value1, value2, value3);
#else
    // Separate calls for different parts
    size_t pos = snprintf(line + pos, sizeof line - pos, "%d", key);
    if (pos < sizeof line)
        pos += snprintf(line + pos, sizeof line - pos, ", %s", value1);
    if (pos < sizeof line)
        pos += snprintf(line + pos, sizeof line - pos, ", %d", value2);
    if (pos < sizeof line)
        pos += snprintf(line + pos, sizeof line - pos, ", %f", value3);
    if (pos < sizeof line)
        pos += snprintf(line + pos, sizeof line - pos, "\n");
#endif
    // Check if line is long enough.
    if (pos >= sizeof line) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Buffer size too small: need %zu bytes\n", pos + 1);
    }
    // Write the values into the file.
    ssize_t len = strlen(line);
    ssize_t nwritten = write(status, line, len);
    if (nwritten != len) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to %s: %zd bytes written, expected %zd.\n",
                filename, nwritten, len);
    }

    // Close the file.
    if (close(status) == -1) {
        perror("Error while closing the file.");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int res;
    res = set_value(10, "abc", 3, 2.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"ASCII text, with no line terminators" means there is no [line ending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) at the end of the file (CR or LF).
It is not an error, it just describes the content of the file.

If you want to add line terminators as said, instead of:

```
...
n = strlen(line);
line[n + 1] = 0;
...
```

Change those 2 lines into the line below for LF (Linux convention):

```
strcat(line, "\n");
```

Or if you want both CR and LF (Windows convention):

```
strcat(line, "\r\n");
```

EDIT: Changed `strncat` into `strcat`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yeah you are right, I just thought about that after posting the answer.